# How to make flutter page scrollable using slivers

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, scrollable, flutter-sliver

I am trying to implement a sliver in CustScrollView, below is my code

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            floating: true,
            snap: true,
            expandedHeight: 300,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              background: Image.asset(
                "assets/images/food6.jpg",
                width: double.maxFinite,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Text("Chinese fruit food details. Chinese fruit food details Chinese fruit food details Chinese fruit food details Chinese fruit food details "),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

the issue is that the page is not scrollable. I have tried to detect where my mistake is coming from but I couldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the text in the **Text()** widget under **SliverToBoxAdapter()** longer than the screen size, scroll will automatically be applied.

Comment: I have same issue but instead of `Text` widget I have `PaginatedDataTable` and it's already wider than screen but horizontall scrolling is not applied or not working. any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
const SliverToBoxAdapter(
  child: Text(
    "Chinese fruit food details. Chinese fruit food details Chinese fruit food details Chinese fruit food details Chinese fruit food details " +
    "Additional content to increase height and trigger scrolling. Additional content to increase height and trigger scrolling.",
  ),
),
```

and

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
  child: CustomScrollView(
    slivers: [
      // ... your slivers
    ],
  ),
);
```